# How to upload test result with dotnetcoretest in Cake to AppVeyor

Tags: c#, .net-core, nunit-3.0, appveyor, build-system

I have a cake file for building my [netstandard library project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) that you can see it in [GitHub home repo](https://github.com/soroshsabz/Commons/blob/master/Build/build.cake).

For integration with [Appveyor CI](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/soroshsabz/commons/builds/30343119) I want to upload test result in this CI and generate coverlet coverage together. for this purpose I write below stage

```
Task("Test")
    .IsDependentOn("Build")
    .Does(() => {
        var settings = new DotNetCoreTestSettings {
        };

        var coverletSettings = new CoverletSettings {
            CollectCoverage = true,
            CoverletOutputFormat = CoverletOutputFormat.opencover,
            CoverletOutputDirectory = Directory(@"./coverage-test/"),
            CoverletOutputName = coverageResultsFileName
        };
 
        DotNetCoreTest(testProject, settings, coverletSettings);
        MoveFile("./coverage-test/" + coverageResultsFileName, artifactsDir + coverageResultsFileName);
        if (AppVeyor.IsRunningOnAppVeyor)
            AppVeyor.UploadTestResults(artifactsDir + coverageResultsFileName, AppVeyorTestResultsType.NUnit3);
});
```

But as you can see in result of [build test section in AppVeyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/soroshsabz/commons/builds/30343119/tests), there is not show any test result and AppVeyor does not show any test result.

**My problem is how to upload test result to AppVeyor with generate coverlet coverage together?**

I found one solution to upload test result in [AppVeyor in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46370959/1539100) but it is not my answer, because if I use `NUnit3` class in cake file, I think indeed AppVeyor run all unit test twice and it is not efficient.